# How to use if else condition on spring roo project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I try to write if else condition on Entity class but when i run tomcat it's not working. It have an error. I curious to know how to write if else condition in spring roo project? And which file i can write that?

i try to test condition by write:(in Student.java)

```
  9 @RooJavaBean
 10 @RooToString
 11 @RooJpaActiveRecord
 12 public class Student {
 13     private long id;
 14     private String name; 
 15     private Integer age; 
 16     if(true){} //test if condition
```

And this's errors when i run tomcat.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project tap: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] Employee.java:[22,1] illegal start of type
[ERROR] Employee.java:[22,4] illegal start of type
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: post the code and the error. you should be able to write if else condition to .java classes. not aspectj files!

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg I can write it to entity class or controller class

Comment: again, edit your post and put the code as you have it. then we can see what can go wrong

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg OK, i show you a samplecode. on code i try to use by insert empty condition on line 16

Comment: You are trying to insert an `if` condition in the middle of a class when it should be inside a method. I think you need to learn some Java first.

Comment: madth3 is right. you have to put the code in a method, then call the method to execute the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure indicate that you have an syntax error.

And yes there in an syntax error in line 16.
You can not write an `if` statement somewhere into an class, it must be in an method!

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Student {
   private long id;
   private String name; 
   private Integer age; 

   public void someMethod() {
       if(1 == 1){
          // if 1 is 1 then do this.
       } else {
         // if 1 is different to 1 then do this.
       }                
   }
```

You should notice, that this Roo classes, are normal Java classes (enhannced by some Roo generated AspectJ files), but this are real classes, but no configuration files.